# A blank space is appearing when I compile latex instead of my stargazer generated table

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I want to print a stargazer generated table from r into my latex document. I created the table named table_1.tex and put it in the same directory as my latex files are. 
First I create a simple dataset to reproduce my data:

```r
vector <- rep(0,72)
for (i in 1:72) {
  vector[i] <- rnorm(1)
}
matrix <- matrix(vector, nrow= 9)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix)

table_1 <- stargazer(data,
                     align=TRUE,
                     title = "Table 1: Main Results",
                     type = "text", 
                     out.header = TRUE,
                     column.labels = c("Modelo", "Modelo", "Modelo","Modelo", "Modelo", "Modelo",
                                       "Modelo", "Modelo", "Modelo"),
                     dep.var.labels=c("log(PIB)","log(PIB)"), 
                     covariate.labels = c("log(DT t)", "Gini t", "log(DT t) * Gini t", "log(DT t-1)",
                                          "Gini t-1", "log(DT t) * Gini t-1", "log(DT t-1) * Gini t-1",
                                          "Mortinf t", "log(Prod t)", "Abertura t", "log(Pop t)"),
                     notes = c("All models were estimated by the fixed effects estimator. The errors are robust to heteroscedasticity and", 
                               "autocovariance. Numbers between parenthesis are the standard-deviations of the coefficients. * represents",
                               "significante at 10\\%, ** at 5\\% and *** at 1\\%."),
                     no.space= TRUE,
                     style = "AER",
                     notes.append = FALSE,
                     notes.align = "l",
                     out = "table_1_1.tex")
```

Then I try to import it in latex:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

blabla

\include{table_1_1.tex}

\end{document}
```

However, when I compile this code, it only outputs "blabla" and not my table. Instead, there is a big, blank space where it should be. I thought it might be because I had included notes written in portuguese in stargazer. Actually, when I try to open the stargazer table file separately, it says that I should change my encoding from UTF-8  to ISO-8859-9. I've changed this in the configurations, but the code still doesn't output the table.
I'm also new to latex, so excuse me if my mistakes are silly.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would be great if you could supply all that is required to reproduce the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you also show `table_test.tex`? Maybe the table is too big and floated somewhere else?

Comment: Is there a way to send the file of my table here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the table exported by stargazer, you will see that it starts by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}
```

As you are importing the table into a document, you dont need that. You can set `out.header = F` in stargazer (or leave the option out, since F is the default), and load the `dcolumn` package in the main document.

Also, I think the better way to import tables is

```
\input{table_1_1.tex}
```

See here for more info:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stargazer/versions/5.2.2/topics/stargazer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Complete answer:

Stargazer

```
table_1 <- stargazer(data,
                     align=TRUE,
                     title = "Table 1: Main Results",
                     type = "text", 
                     column.labels = c("Modelo", "Modelo", "Modelo","Modelo", "Modelo", "Modelo",
                                       "Modelo", "Modelo", "Modelo"),
                     dep.var.labels=c("log(PIB)","log(PIB)"), 
                     covariate.labels = c("log(DT t)", "Gini t", "log(DT t) * Gini t", "log(DT t-1)",
                                          "Gini t-1", "log(DT t) * Gini t-1", "log(DT t-1) * Gini t-1",
                                          "Mortinf t", "log(Prod t)", "Abertura t", "log(Pop t)"),
                     notes = c("All models were estimated by the fixed effects estimator. The errors are robust to heteroscedasticity and", 
                               "autocovariance. Numbers between parenthesis are the standard-deviations of the coefficients. * represents",
                               "significante at 10\\%, ** at 5\\% and *** at 1\\%."),
                     no.space= TRUE,
                     style = "AER",
                     notes.append = FALSE,
                     notes.align = "l",
                     out = "table_1_1.tex")
```

Latex:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

blabla

\input{table_1_1.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've corrected the header. But now it says there is an illegal character in the table. Could this be because of the notes I've written?

Comment: Mh mh, I do not get any error running the code above.